# ASP.NET MVC Entry Point

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dll, environment

Quick question regarding the execution of ASP.NET MVC applications.

As far as I understand the projects of an MVC application are compiled into DLL files. In an MVC application environment, is there an executable program which links in these DLL's? Is there a program generated which is essentially the MVC engine using the DLL's which sits on a server and called upon when the domain URL gets a request?

I'm probably wrong, but this is how I imagine it in my head :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a very large amount of work that goes on behind the scenes. At a *very* broad level, a request is made to the url and the server returns a string.

Getting there is the interesting part.

So first, there is a server setup. Let's just assume it is using IIS. IIS is exposes a "default application". This application can be accessed through the IP address of the server (often by way of port forwarding through a firewall).

The information for the application is kept in a folder that is referenced in IIS. That folder structure contains .dll's, images, scripts, .cshtml, config files, etc. The `.dll` that shares the name of the application is the one starts the application off. Inside of that `.dll` is the asp.net MVC application.

The application is only running while the application pool is active. The application pool is only active for some variable period of time after a request, and if it was inactive then the request must wait for the pool to start and the application to start.

Starting the application means executing the `.dll`. This will also cascade to executing related dll's depending on the config files and reference setup. Finally, we are to where asp.net MVC starts.

The asp.net mvc application will begin by instantiating a routing class which is the base of the entire entry. This routing class takes a request string, breaks it down based on rules in the routing dictionary, and then uses reflection to instantiate the correlating controller and invoke the relative method.

Once the action method is executing it takes the parameters injected into it from the invoke and does whatever it does - orders pizza. The server thinks while the pizza is ordered. Once ordered, the method returns a view. The view is just a way to compose the information from ordering the pizza. It is still executing server side. Once the view completes, along with information passed from the ordering pizza aspect, the entire return value is written to the response stream.

At that point the response is rendered in the browser, any script sent is executed, and the pizza is hopefully placed in the oven in the near future.

[image]
<sub>(source: [dotnet-tricks.com](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Content/images/mvc/ASP.NETMVC5Pipeline.png))</sub>

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much! I can't make any votes yet as I haven't got enough reputation :)

Comment: Another question regarding the default application :) If we had a server using IIS and had multiple MVC applications on there, would there be multiple default applications, one for each application? And is the 'default application' generic to all applications hosted or are they specific to each type of application? Many thanks again.

Comment: Is the 'default application' essentially the ASP.NET MVC engine?